# not able to get good quality image bitmap from MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch good quality image using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

code:-

```
takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                "com.oreda.odisha.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);
                    }
                /*imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                    cameraResultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent);
                }
            }
        });
```

code to create file:-

```
   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        
        return image;
    }
```

code added in manifest:-

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.oreda.odisha.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

code in file_paths:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.oreda.odisha/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

code

I am handling the result in following code. but still getting null bitmap

```
    private void cameraImage(Intent data) throws IOException {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", imageUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
        }


        Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

        if (null==photo && imageUri != null) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; // or Bitmap.Config.RGB_565


                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);
                // Further processing with the bitmap
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    // Process the bitmap
                    
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Bitmap is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Handle the exception (e.g., show an error message)
            }
        }
        addToJSON();
    }
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    try {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        cameraImage(data);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I have tested in two devices lenovo Tab K10(android OS 12) and samsung galaxy s20 FE(android OS 13) . In both the phones I am getting null bitmap at both method where I was trying to fetch Bitmap:-

1. Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
2. Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

Kindly help how can I get good quality image using camera intent.

I have tried the following steps to fetch image:-

1. Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
2. Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

I am expecting a image bitmap having high resolution.

Comment: You may not have sufficient heap space to read in the full-resolution photo.

Comment: applied android:largeHeap="true" flag to manifest. but still getting same null Bitmap.

Comment: What impact `android:largeHeap` has, if any, depends on device model. What are you looking to do that requires the entire photo to be loaded into heap space as a `Bitmap`?

Comment: `imageUri = data.getData();` That will not give you an uri for your file. It does not work that way.

Comment: data.getData() is null so imageUri = data.getData(); is never executed . so value in imageUri  remains same as it was in line imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                "com.oreda.odisha.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);

Comment: I will ask again: what are you looking to do that requires the entire photo to be loaded into heap space as a `Bitmap`? For example, if you are looking to display the image, [you do not need to load the entire image into heap space](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view).

Comment: i want to load the entire photo to be loaded into heap space add some text on the Bitmap. then show the new Bitmap in ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working solution:-

```
private void cameraImage(Intent data) throws IOException {
    
    Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    //compress
    //rotate according to EXIF interface data


    if (null != photo ) {
        try {
            addTextToCompessedImage(photo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle the exception (e.g., show an error message)
        }
    }
    
}
```